# Creating mulitiple Data Types in Java

Tags: java

What I have here is the skeleton of the project in Java. This is based off of creating data types and I will basically have it find the area, perimeter, find if they intersect or contain each other. I understand the formulas I need to use but how would I actually create rectangle b so just like the initial rectangle I have to have an x,y center and a width and height? I had tried in a similar fashion to declare rectangle b but it refuses to assign any of the variables.

In order to find if it rectangle b intersects with the other rectangle I need to define it in order to do calculations for the corners of the rectangle etc, here is my code:

```
public class OwnRectangles {

    private final double x,y;  //center of rectangle
    private final double width; //width of rectangle
    private final double height; //height of rectangle

    public Rectangle(double x0, double y0, double w, double h)
    {
        x=x0;
        y=y0;
        width=w;
        height=h;
    }
    public double area()
    {
        return width*height;
    }

    public double perimeter()
    {
        return height*2 + width*2;
    }

    public boolean intersects(Rectangle b)
    {

    }

    public boolean contains(Rectangle b)
    {

    }

    public void draw(Rectangle b)
    {
        /*Draw rectangle on standard drawing*/
    }

}
```

I essentially am trying to create another rectangle, I tried something like this which would not work:

```
public OwnRectanglesb(double x2, double y2, double w2, double h2)
{
    x=x2;
    y=y2;
    width=w2;
    height=h2;
}
```

Not only does this name not match the OwnRectangles b, but the public... is supposed to be just OwnRectangles if that makes sense. Very simply I want to define a second rectangle to use.

Comment: a) for class `OwnRectangles` the constructor should have the same name; b) last two methods are missing return statements (so it won't compile); c) what do you mean by "it refuses to assign any of the variables"?

Comment: @khachik when I try creating a Rectangle B, now changed to match the name properly as others just mentioned below, it won't allow me to assign something to the x value such as the original rectangle.

Comment: Your code does not compile and the compiler error should be a hint as to what is wrong with you corde (check answers below). "*`double x0, double y0, double w, double h`*" - Please don't do that. Give the parameters some meaningful names.

Comment: @Turing85 I will this is just a skeleton as mentioned above but thank you for the advice

Comment: @khachik never mind solved it myself! I was declaring something like ownrectangles b when it is NOT supposed to have a space. Edit not solved because it still would have to match the name of the project so I cant use ownrectanglesb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer. To do so I just create different instances of the class, putting it directly under:

```
public OwnRectangles(double x0, double y0, double w, double h)
{
    x=x0;
    y=y0;
    width=w;
    height=h;

    Rectangle a = new OwnRectangles(//put arguments here);
    Rectangle b = new OwnRectangles(//put arguments here);
}
```

As can be seen I have created two different rectangles based off of the class rectangle, and of course in the parenthesis I would put the arguments allowing the user to set the width height etc of the rectangles to anything that they want.

Answer (score 1):

The class `OwnRectangle` needs to match the use of `Rectangle` in your code, for example change to:

```
public class Rectangle /* CHANGED FROM OwnRectangle to Rectangle */ {
    private final double x,y;  //center of rectangle
    private final double width; //width of rectangle
    private final double height; //height of rectangle

    public Rectangle(double x0, double y0, double w, double h)
    {
        x=x0;
        y=y0;
        width=w;
        height=h;
    }
    public double area()
    {
        return width*height;
    }

    public double perimeter()
    {
        return height*2 + width*2;
    }

    public boolean intersects(Rectangle b)
    {

    }

    public boolean contains(Rectangle b)
    {

    }

    public void draw(Rectangle b)
    {
    /*Draw rectangle on standard drawing*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to create the rectangle objects and determine if they intersect, your code would look something like this:

```
Rectangle firstRectangle = new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4);
Rectangle secondRectangle = new Rectangle(5, 6, 7, 8);
boolean intersects = firstRectangle.intersects(secondRectangle);
```

Where the values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8` are just arbitrary values you would replace with the true values. Then in your `intersects` method you would just compare x, y, width, and height to b.x, b.y, b.width, and b.height. Lastly, all references to the Rectangle object should be called the same thing `Rectangle`, not interchanging `Rectangle` and `OwnRectangle`.

Comment: This is a nice example however I am looking to set up a completely different rectangle because I then want to use the x,y,width and height in order to find the corners of the rectangle and use this for my calculation

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is `OwnRectangles` but what appears to be a constructor  is named `Rectangle`. The constructor name must match the class name, otherwise it's just a method. You could correct it by writing:

```
public class OwnRectangles {

  private final double x,y;  //center of rectangle
  private final double width; //width of rectangle
  private final double height; //height of rectangle

  public OwnRectangles(double x0, double y0, double w, double h) {
  ...
```